# Angular-cli Digital Ocean deployment

Tags: node.js, express, angular, deployment, digital-ocean

I got problem with running my **Angular 2** app on **Digital Ocean**. I'm trying to deploy my app on cloud server, everything starts just fine, but when i try to connect to app on specified port server is just not responding. I'm clueless since I can't find any help, and I just can't understand why only angular-cli frontend won't run, because when I'm connecting to Node.js Express server or MongoDB server that i also run on my droplet there's no problem with connecting to them. Firewall is temporarily turned off. I'd glad if any of you could help me out.

Comment: Please, tell us more about the environment. Is it an Linux Server? Are you using Node/Express as back-end? Which port are you using and how are your firewall configured? Why don't you make a build using `ng build` and serve it as your front-end app?

Comment: @vinagreti Server is Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64, Node/Express is for back-end, app is running on port 4200, firewall is disabled, I have used ng build and i got dist folder but I don't know how to serve it

Comment: Angular 2 is HTML + JS (static files), so you can serve it using Apache, Express, amazon S3, even google drive. Here are an example of serving static files in express: http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-serve-static-files-with-express

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is HTML + JS (static files), so you can serve it using Apache, Express, amazon S3, even google drive. Here are an example of serving static files in express: http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-serve-static-files-with-express